# Azure DevOps dashboard: show deployment status of release pipeline in another project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I want to show the deployment status of a release pipeline on my Azure DevOps dashboard, but the pipeline is in another project.

I tried using some of the standard widgets for this but they don't give me the option to use a pipeline from a different project.